# Saving user input to a page

Tags: php, html, mysql

I feel i am missing a crucial link in my design and i was hoping some fine programmer could fill me in (this is not really my field of experience)

**What I have**

page - form.html

```
<div style="text-align:left">
<form action="addtoserver.php" method="post">
Server Name: <input type="text" name="servername"><br>
<br>
Server Address: <input type="text" name="serveraddress"><br>
<br>
Port Number: <input type="text" name="portnumber"><br>
<br>
Server Description :<TEXTAREA NAME="description" ROWS=3 COLS=30 ></TEXTAREA>
<br>
<input name="Submit" type="submit" value="Add Server" />
</form>
<div style="text-align:left">
```

page - addtoserver.php

```
<html>
<body>
Server Name :<?php echo $_POST["servername"]; ?><br>
<br>
Server Address : <?php echo $_POST["serveraddress"]; ?><br>
<br>
Port Number : <?php echo $_POST["portnumber"]; ?><br>
<br>
Server Description : <?php echo $_POST["description"]; ?><br>

<?php

$ip = $_POST['serveraddress'];
$port = $_POST['portnumber'];

if (!$socket = @fsockopen($ip, $port, $errno, $errstr, 30))
{
  echo "<centre><font color='red'><strong>Server Is Offline!</strong></font></center>";
}
else 
{
  echo "<centre><font color='green'><strong>Server Is Online!</strong></font></centre>";  

  fclose($socket);
}

?>

</body>
</html>
```

Everything is all gravy

**Purpose**

I designed this for the purpose of my website a user will click a link "Add server" and will be directed to the form page, they will fill out the form page and once submitted be directed to the addserver.php page.
On this page i wont the post to pertinently stay there and the next user to  to come in and add his server and for that post to be listed underneath.

**My Dilemma**

I am not sure what the next step is to take, would i have to add the users input to Mysql and then export it from Mysql to the page or is there another way. would i have to rite a PHP script in order to get the posts to come in one after the other if imported from the data base.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I am not sure what the next step is to take, would i have to add the users input to Mysql and then export it from Mysql to the page?

If you require persistent data then you'll sure need some static storage such as a database or a XML file. In both way, yes you want to store the user input into it (make sure you fully understand the security need behind such an action) and then retrieve it from there.

Comment: OK thank you for that, I am currently running a MySQL database that can be used to store the data, the data base is secure however by default is the data sent in clear text.

Comment: @bennyboy, it's not about the safety of the database per se, but more about how to correctly perform database actions without letting the user inject an malicious string.